# Lambda jooq wrong date from mysql

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, aws-lambda, jooq

In AWS Lambda I am using jOOQ to read data from a MySql database.

In a simple select query as follow I am reading a column whose type is 'date'.

I tried searching for the solution, but no luck.

```
context.select(Transaction.TRANSACTION.TRANSACTION_DATE)
 .from(Transaction.TRANSACTION)
 .where(Transaction.TRANSACTION.ORDER_ID.eq(orderId))
 .fetch();
```

When I print the result set date is of the previous day always.

**Database Date   =>  2019-03-12**

**jOOQ result set Date =>  2019-03-11**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.!

Comment: This looks like a time zone issue. Does your JVM have the same time zone as your MySQL database?

Comment: Yes, timezones are same. AWS is in **ap-south-1**. 
Both Lambda and RDS are in the same AWS account.

Comment: What do you get when you fetch that date using JDBC?